# wrong syntax using ng init with an array of objets angularjs

Tags: html, arrays, angularjs

I have the following html page below where I want to use the order by filter in a list, I am trying to create a tutorial so here I didn't want to use the JavaScript file just yet.
I also made a Fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/AnaSeq/tqgpr4jL/

What is wrong with my syntax? I suspect it's on ng-init

```
 <!DOCTYPE html>
     <html ng-app="">
     <head><title></title></head>
     <body>
     <div ng-init=" 
            names = [
          {name: 'John',   phone: '555-1212',  age: 10},
          {name: 'Mary',   phone: '555-9876',  age: 19},
          {name: 'Mike',   phone: '555-4321',  age: 21},
          {name: 'Adam',   phone: '555-5678',  age: 35},
          {name: 'Julie',  phone: '555-8765',  age: 29}
          ]">
     <h3> Looping with the ng-repeat Directive </h3>
     <ul>
     <li ng-repeat="person in names | order by: 'name'">{{person.name}}</li>
     </ul>
     </div>
     <script src="angular.js"></script>
     </body>
     </html>
```

Comment: it's `orderBy` filter, not `order by`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
<html ng-app="">

  <head>
    <title></title>
  </head>

  <body>
    <div ng-init=" 
  names = [
   {name: 'John',   phone: '555-1212',  age: 10},
      {name: 'Mary',   phone: '555-9876',  age: 19},
      {name: 'Mike',   phone: '555-4321',  age: 21},
      {name: 'Adam',   phone: '555-5678',  age: 35},
      {name: 'Julie',  phone: '555-8765',  age: 29}
   ]">
      <h3> Looping with the ng-repeat Directive </h3>
      <ul>
        <li ng-repeat="person in names | orderBy: 'name'">{{person.name}}</li>
      </ul>
    </div>
    <script src="angular.js"></script>
  </body>

</html>
```

**Issue with "order by" replace it with "orderBy"**